# Getting a global value from a provider with less boilerplate code

Tags: angular, typescript

If I have a configurationService provider that has a getServerContextPath() getter (not async), can I get the value without initializing the service in the constructor?

My current implementation:

```
export class FilterCarDataService {
    private urlFilteredData: string;
    constructor(
        private readonly configurationService: ConfigurationService
    ) {
        this.urlFilteredData = `/${this.configurationService.getServerContextPath}/utilities/filterdata`;
    }
}
```

Things I don't like about this implementation:

1) In every file I need the server context path I have to initialize the service in the constructor

2) I cannot declare `urlFilteredData` as `readonly`, because I have to reassign it with the server context path.

Is there an implementation for a global variable (server context path) that doesn't require that much boilerplate code in every file I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a class with static fields?

```
class Configuration {
    public static readonly ServerContextPath = 'abc';
}
```

and usage - `Configuration.ServerContextPath`